# Any latest linux distro which gives full root access ( NO SUDO )?

Tags: linux, linux-distributions, sudo, root, su

Is there Any latest linux distro which gives full root access ( NO SUDO ) ? I want to use it for programming in which I have to use / file system very frequently.

What I need is any good linux distro with Nice Installer like Synaptic and Fast Bootup speed like ubuntu 9.04.

Does Fedora 11 gives full root access?

Thanks, Sunny.

Comment: Good luck on not trashing things by mistake.  It's real easy to screw up in root, which is why most of us use user accounts and sudo.

Comment: @DavidThornley: screwing up in root is only a sign of lacking experience.

Comment: @XXL:  I can screw up lots of things I've got experience in.  If I'm running as root, I can screw things up real good.  All it takes is typing something normal not quite in the right context.  I took to typing the command, sitting on my hands, and looking at the command carefully before hitting enter while in root.

Comment: @DavidThornley: I've been running only root for multiple years and I am yet to screw up anything. Guess it's a "person" thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Becoming root for one session:

In Ubuntu you can become root for the remainder of the session by typing:

```
# old-school method
sudo su

# new hotness, comes highly recommended
sudo -i
```

More [information](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=963243) and [related](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) reading.

### Permanently enabling the root account:

Further, you may permanently enable the root account by typing:

```
sudo passwd root
```

and providing a root password.  You can then log in as root at your leisure without needing to use `sudo`.

Comment: Is this possible to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: It is indeed possible with Ubuntu

Comment: According to the #ubuntu IRC channel, the forums, and mailing lists, `sudo -i` is the recommended way to get a root shell. Please update your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Puppy Linux boots and will auto-login with root user by default.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just log in as root when you start up? You provide the root password in the install process of most distributions (Fedora as you mentioned, is an example). If you forgot this you can reset it from a user account:

```
sudo passwd root
```

it will then ask you for your new UNIX password.

If you'd like to become root temporarily **AND** use **root's environment settings**:

```
sudo su -
```

Comment: sudo and su are overlapping programs, so using them together is a bit wasteful.  If you want root's login environment (except for using your current DISPLAY etc.), use sudo -i.

Comment: @Lee B: True, but...to `su -` you need to recall the root password (and have a valid one set), while the sudo lets you in with only your user password.

Answer (score 1):

fedora offer full root access by typing

```
su
```

Or you can use your debian based distro (ubuntu) and type

```
sudo bash
```

to get semi-permanent root shell.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I'll share an answer for anyone else that Google may lead here. There are a number of Puppy Linux varients available from a list on their website: http://puppylinux.org/wikka/PuppyVersion

Puppy is designed to be a single user system and therefore does away with a lot of Linux's usual over the top security measures, but be aware that this will offend a great many people (insufferable A-holes) in the Linux community who are seemingly obsessed with the idea that Linux's greatest feature is security.

While this may be true for them, it's not what everyone wants and as an open-source platform all people should be entitled to a distro or work-around that suits their needs. (ie. if you don't have an answer for him just stfu and keep your ideas about root/sudo to yourself).

Comment: This duplicates Anony Moose's answer (and adds commentary that isn't really appropriate in an answer).  As such, it's likely to attract downvotes, which will detract from your accumulating enough rep to comment.  You might want to consider deleting this post.

Comment: I 'considered deleting it' and decided not to. The commentary is exceedingly necessary to give voice to those who are tried with the problems which plague the Linux design philosophy and the attitudes presented by who champion it. Linux is in desperate need of distros which provide freedom to the user out of the box; WITHOUT using the terminal. If that rubs you the wrong way: good. That means that you at least took note.

Comment: Yes, as a long term user of  Windows (from 3.1 to 11) of a very customized OS on a single use PC, with only two actual infections in 23 years and nothing recent  (thank God,  pray and press),  then if I were to switch to Linux (having tried every major and many minor distros over the years),  I would have to run as root many times, using my slow stiff arthritic typo-fingers to do so.

Thus my favorite is Puppy. But even then, aside from the memory Windows runs out of (despite 64GB and not gaming, video editing),  then Windows has yet to do things that would justify the time and energy that..